# REST - deal with modification from server side after PUT (such as the date of creation)

Tags: rest, http

Since PUT is idempotent, how handle the situation which with the server add or change informations from the object send by the client ?

If **all** my resources have 'createdDate' and 'updatedDate' fields, should the client **always** use PATCH method (and never PUT) if I don't want the client to choose the value of these fields ?

Answer (score 0):

PUT *replaces* the resource pointed to by the URL.
PATCH *modifies* the resource pointed to by the URL.

If you are modifying some subset of the properties of a resource, then PATCH is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Just because PUT replaces an object in full doesn't mean you have to expose all fields for update. If you want create and updated dates done only on the backend, then do not expose them in either your PUT or PATCH methods.

Your RESTful API does not have to be exactly the same as your persistence/database methods.

Comment: But if I justly want to expose these dates. Considering many of my resources have this kind of field, should I alawys use PATCH. It's a bit confusing because PATCH is a recent method. How did we handle without its release ?

Comment: Before `PATCH` we used `POST` to update resources.  Some purists still prefer to use `POST`.  `POST` is the wildcard method of the HTTP methods.  It can be used for anything that doesn't quite fit any other method -- including updates.